# .Net collapsible panel or collapsible link control

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms, c#-4.0, user-interface

I am trying to develop a quick links panel like in windows explorer. I may be using a wrong name for that control, so i have attached the screen shot. Before developing a custom control, I did a research on the existing controls and couldn't find a control like that. I am not convinced, hence this control is used over a decade and still not available in visual studio forms developement. May be this is included in WPF. But is there alternative for windows forms.

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [WinForms: How do I make a collapsible UI region on the form, like Visual Studio's toolbox?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1888986/winforms-how-do-i-make-a-collapsible-ui-region-on-the-form-like-visual-studio)

Comment: Also see this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3795005/add-an-expander-collapse-expand-to-a-panel-winform Both suggest using a SplitContainer among other answers.

Answer (score 1):

The control is called an [Expander](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.expander.aspx) in `WPF`. There is no equivalent in `Windows Forms` though.

If you want to implement one yourself, have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12835/XP-Style-Collapsible-GroupBox) control, it seems to be just like what you are looking for. Maybe you can take it as a base and modify it.